# Div не растягивается по высоте

Tags: html, css

Почему левое меню не растягивается по высоте контента? 
Код ниже просто для того, чтобы вопрос разрешили опубликовать

```html
<html style="height: 100%;border:1px solid yellow;">

<body style="height: 100%;border:1px solid green;">
  <div style="float: left; min-height: 100%; border:1px solid red;">Левое меню</div>
  <div>Какой-то контент</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Все прекрасно растягивается....

Comment: Задайте background color и посмотрите

Comment: @Air
https://codepen.io/Dgacarda/pen/YJjxvJ ссылку на codepen почему-то удалили, левое меню не растягивается

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич https://codepen.io/Dgacarda/pen/YJjxvJ ссылку на codepen почему-то удалили, левое меню не растягивается

Comment: У вас левое меню на всю  высоту, на сколько я вижу

Comment: @СашаЛямин, посмотри там сылка была пустая

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример, блок div автоматически принимает размер дочерних элементов. Указывать минимальную высоту не стоит :)

```
<body>
    <div style="float: left; width: 300px; border: 1px solid red">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 305px; border: 1px solid green">
        <p>Text Text</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся флексом. Задай родительскому контейнеру `display: flex` и `align-items: stretch`, это позволит всем дочерним элементам растягиваться по высоте контейнера.

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
}

.page__nav {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.page__content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
 <nav class="nav page__nav">
  Левое меню
 </nav>
 <main class='content page__content'>
  Какой-то контент
 </main>
</div>
```